# Making nav item active based on page

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

There is a sub nav as follows:

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav span3">
    <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav">
        <li><a href="/bio"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Bio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/resume"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>Resume</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is being loaded by :

```
@{Html.RenderAction("SubNav");}
```

which invokes a non controller action:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult SubNav()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Now based on page, how do i add `active` to the class of li within subnav so i can make it show as selected/active?

Comment: i am not doing it on master page, i saw that question already.did u read the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the action name. find the action name on run time, pass it to view by a model or ViewBag.

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult SubNav()
    {
            var rd = Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
            string currentAction = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
            string currentController = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
            string currentArea = rd.Values["area"] as string;
            ViewBag.ActionName = currentAction;
            return PartialView();
    }
```

in View:

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav span3">
    <ul class="nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav">
        <li><a href="/bio"><i class="icon-chevron-right  @(ViewBag.ActionName == "bio" ? "ActiveClass" : "")" ></i>Bio</a></li>
        <li><a href="/resume"><i class="icon-chevron-right  @(ViewBag.ActionName == "resume" ? "ActiveClass" : "")"></i>Resume</a></li> 
</ul>
```